# How to make Clang on Windows link against different runtimes

Tags: c++, windows, runtime, clang, clang++

While attempting to build a personal project in C++, I've hit a problem. I'm unsure when it manifested as I normally work on the project in a Linux environment but want the project to work on Windows.

Unfortunately the compiler I'm using, Clang, has begun throwing the following error at me:

```
libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib(operations.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in buffer.obj
```

The problem is I have no idea how to tell Clang which runtime the underlying compiler should use and I do not wish to use `clang-cl` at this time if I don't have to.

What is the correct way to make Clang on Windows link against the dynamic runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of what I did stopped the linker from complaining, but in my build script, I specified `-D_MT -D_DLL` as two of my compiler and linker options and for my linker I had to disable the default libraries (`-Xlinker /NODEFAULTLIB`) and manually specify which versions of the runtimes to link against (in my case, `-lmsvcrt -lucrt -lmsvcprt -lvcruntime`). These two changes seem to have stopped all linkage and compilation errors.

Comment: `_MT` = multithreaded, `_DLL` = dynamic link the runtime. These compilation flags need to match the libraries which you link against.